# How to tell the difference between a MySQL GA release and milestone build

Tags: mysql, upgrade

I'm working on upgrading our product's MySQL version.  MySQL documentation states that [Upgrades between milestone releases (or from a milestone release to a GA release) are not supported](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading.html#upgrade-procedure-logical)

I'm trying to determine if the version path we're traversing is not supported (5.5.30 to 5.6.26).

It isn't clear on their [archived release page](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/) how to distinguish a GA from a milestone build.  Is there a place with additional information about each release? If not how can I tell the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Release Notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/).

Version 5.5.8 and all later versions are GA in MySQL Server 5.5.

Version 5.6.10 and later versions are GA in MySQL Server 5.6.

Non-GA releases are the versions prior to these, which shouldn't be used in production, because (among other reasons) there are sometimes breaking changes prior to GA.  Once the series goes GA, these are not supposed to happen.

---

Note that there's a difference between "not supported" and "impossible."  In MySQL compatibility parlance, "not supported" sometimes means "if you read and understand the release notes for each and every intermediate version, know exactly what you're doing, proceed deliberately, and take appropriate precautions, it might work just fine, but don't say we said it might work just fine, because we didn't say that."  In other words, it's literally not *supported* in the sense that failures on such paths will not be considered to be something that merits a remedy or fix or workaround.